# add values from the latest year to those of the last month of the previous year in pandas dataframe groupby year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to group by year in this example dataframe and if the sum of "Severe cases U5" == 0 and the sum of  "Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment" is greater than 0, I want to add the sum of "Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment" to the last month of the previous year. See my data:

```
data = [[2020, 11,  1, 1], [2020, 12,  2, 2], [2021, 1, 0, 0], [2021, 1, 0, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year', 'month', 'Severe cases U5', 'Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'])
```

I started by writing what you see below (not sure how to index groupby objects) but kept getting this error :TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
for group in df.groupby('year'):
    if group['Severe cases U5'].sum() == 0 and group['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'].sum() > 0:
         pre_year = group['year'] - 1
```

Update: I figured out the group iteration. Now need to figure out the row iteration. That part of the code does not work. see below:

```
for year, group in df.groupby('year'):
        if (group['Severe cases U5'].sum() == 0 and group['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'].sum() > 0):
        
            year_current = np.unique(group['year'])[0] -1
            excess_death = group['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'].sum()
            group['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'] = 0
            print(excess_death)
            print(year_current)
    for month_row, row in group.iterrows():  
            if (row['year'] == year and row['month'] == 12): #not working but what i am trying to do
                    row['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'] =+ excess_death
                    print(row['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'])
```

Comment: You seem to be wanting to iterate over each year, right?

Comment: Yes! the final dataframe should have the 'Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment' in 2021 added to that of month 12 in 2020.

Comment: please add the expected output column

Comment: @anon01 see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally! Bulky solution but it works.

```
data = [[2020, 11,  1, 1], [2020, 12,  2, 2], [2021, 1, 0, 0], [2021, 1, 0, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year', 'month', 'Severe cases U5', 'Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'])

for year, group in df.groupby('year'):
        if (group['Severe cases U5'].sum() == 0 and group['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'].sum() > 0):
        
            year_current = np.unique(group['year'])[0] -1
            excess_death = group['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'].sum()
            for month_row, row in group.iterrows():
                if (row['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'] > 0):
                      df.loc[month_row, 'Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'] = 0
           
      
        
for year, group in df.groupby('year'):
        for month_row, row in group.iterrows():
            if (row['year'] == year_current and row['month'] == 12):
            #not working but what i am trying to do
                 death_previous=row['Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'] + excess_death
                 df.loc[month_row, 'Num_U5_Received_Severe_Treatment'] = death_previous
df
```